# Single Side Buffer pyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, vector, buffer

I am trying to create a single side distance buffer around a line on QGIS.

Here is the code I am writing but I don't get the expected result:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer","input.shp",0.5821,25,False,"output.shp",side=left)
```

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a `fixed distance buffer` when you should be using a `single sided buffer`. Please see usage examples below.

For QGIS 3:

```
x = processing.run("qgis:singlesidedbuffer", {'INPUT':'input.shp','DISTANCE':10,'SIDE':0,'SEGMENTS':8,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

For QGIS 2.X, 5th parameter indicates side (0=right, 1=left):

```
x = processing.runalg("gdalogr:singlesidedbuffersandoffsetlinesforlines","input.shp",0,"geometry","10",1,False,None,False,"",None)
```

EDIT:
To add the resulting layer to the map, use the following command:

```
layer = iface.addVectorLayer(x['OUTPUT_LAYER'], "Single Buffer", "ogr")
```

Comment: Sure, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank again, 
I think I am doing it wrong. Here is what I get when I run the code. FYI, the new shapefile (with the buffer) is not created.

"processing.runalg("gdalogr:singlesidedbuffersandoffsetlinesforlines","input.shp",0,'geometry',10,1,False,None,False,None,"output.shp")

{'OUTPUT_LAYER': 'output.shp'}"

Comment: I think you're mixing the two usage examples. Try to use only the second line I wrote, changing the parameters appropriately (you also need to first `import processing` in case you didn't already). The OUTPUT_LAYER part shouldn't be used in QGIS 2.

Comment: Hi, So the code I wrote in my previous message i.e.  {'OUTPUT_LAYER': 'output.shp'}" is actually something I get from the python consol after running the code : "processing.runalg("gdalogr:singlesidedbuffersandoffsetlinesforlines","input.shp",0,'geometry',10,1,False,None,False,"output.shp",None)

Hence I guess there is another problem.

Comment: There is no problem. The layer, as you showed, is generated correctly. The return value is a Python dictonary. See edited below above how to access the layer. Hope that works

Comment: OK PROBLEM SOLVED. Thank you a lot @15Step: 
For those that are interested here is the code :

`layer = iface.addVectorLayer(processing.runalg('gdalogr:singlesidedbuffersandoffsetlinesforlines',"/Users/path/input.shp",0,"geometry","0.1808",1,False,None,False,"",None)["OUTPUT_LAYER"], "Single Buffer", "ogr")`

Comment: Great! Can you please mark the question as solved (click the green arrow)? Thanks!